# how to display notifications in the wordpress menu when a new post is published

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, menus, notifications

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have created a custom post type called "news" and I would like it to be the blog on my site. I have created a news page and have the post displayed there. I have also placed this page in my wordpress menu, so that the users can get to it faster. What I would ultimately like to do is have a notification ( in this case a graphic or red circle with a plus sign) in the menu on top of the word "news" appear when a new "news" post is published. I have searched for a better understanding of this might work but no cigar.

I would imagine that it involves javascript. I cannot find what happens after a post is published on wordpress. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: The question here is: when is something "new"? Since last time a visitor passed by (cookie needed)? Since last time a registered user passed by (check the user profile)? Since an hour ago (check publish time)?

Comment: hey @cjbj thanks for the response, It would be something "new" is since last time a visitor passed by, I think the cookie would be the best.